# Using a SQL TVF on every value of a column

Tags: sql

I have a table where there is no unique identifier and is structured like this:

| timestamp | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 0.12 |
| 1 | a | 0.231 |
| 0 | b | 0.23 |
| 2 | c | 0.01 |

I am trying to use a table-valued-function that only takes in a timestamp and value:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.12 |
| 1 | 0.231 |
| 0 | 0.23 |
| 2 | 0.01 |

The function adds some columns *x, y, z*... to the table above. I'd like to use the function to perform this analysis on every category and produce an output like:

| timestamp | category | value | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 0.12 | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | a | 0.231 |  |  |  |
| 0 | b | 0.23 |  |  |  |
| 2 | c | 0.01 |  |  |  |

Intuitively, I'd like to take a single value of category, say category *a*, ignore the rest, use this table-valued function and join this result with my original table.

```
WITH input_table as 
(
SELECT timestamp, value
WHERE value='a'
FROM table
)

SELECT x, y, z
FROM tvf(
Table input_table);

-- Join this table with original table
```

However, I'd like to do this for *every* value of category, not just 'a'. Is there a way to do this in SQL? I suspect a CROSS APPLY operation could help me, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Can be done with correlated subqueries or using window functions. Can you provide an example of how you want to compute x, y, and/or z?

Comment: Also, the solution can be dependant on the specific database and version of it. What database are you using?

Comment: *x, y, z* are results of a time-series analysis that simply looks at time-stamps and values over the entire table and generates confidence intervals. @TheImpaler